# Listening for javascript touch events but still allowing default scrolling behaviour

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

I am trying to implement a scrollable element for a mobile app and it looks like you must use preventDefault on the initial touchStart event, otherwise the browser will not fire all the touchMove events (presumably for performance reasons).

So it would seem that if I want to allow touch scrolling on an overflown element, the user will not be able to scroll the page as per usual when touching that element. This is problematic if the overflown element takes up a large portion of the viewport.

Is their a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library

http://api.mutado.com/mobile/mtdtouch/js/

The "core" javascript includes a base UIComponent optimized for touch events (webkit).
The UI.Scroll component in example manage the "prevent default issue" for you.

Try to subclass the UIComponent and implement your own events handler like this

```
$MTD.YourOwnComponent = $.klass( $MTD.UIComponent, {    

    touchesBegan: function( e ) {
        // your stuff
    },

    touchesMoved: function( e ) {
        // your stuff   
    },

    touchesEnded: function( e ) {
        // your stuff
    }

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple workaround: **drop the `touchstart` handler**. You can reconstruct most of what's going on with just the `touchmove`, `touchend`, and `touchleaving` handlers.

In the browser I tested with (Chrome), scrolling happens as long as you don't have a `touchstart` handler; it doesn't care about the other ones. As long as you aren't actively calling `ev.preventDefault` in the `touchmove` handlers, scrolling works.

Assuming what you want to do will work fine despite only finding out about a touch when the finger starts moving, instead of when the finger initially lands, this workaround should work acceptably.

... And also I'm assuming other browsers use the same logic as Chrome.